# Semi circle progress bar in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android

I would like to make a semi circle progress bar in Android using Java. I would like it to animate with respect to time, and to partially shade the semicircle. For example:

[image: semi circle progress bar that animate with respect to time and shade below area in android in java]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried. If you want others to write full code for you, you should consider hiring a freelancer. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy. Create a class that extends `View`. `canvas.drawArc()` for filled arc. And for dashed arc and set

```
paintDashedLine.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 20, 15 }, 0));
```

Numbers in array are my preference, you set them as you need. Play with arc start and sweep angles, you will figure it out it's easy.

For image. Get a Bitmap fro assets(search SO if you don't know how)
To set position of image use cos and sin like

```
x = Xcenter + cos(angle);
y = Xcenter + sin(angle);
```

Angle should be radians of course. That's it.

Comment: thanks to reply, I am beginner in this field, please brief it with some example